# Shorten Tikz Edges from node to node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am making simple Finite State Machines for a paper. My code is listed below:

```
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata} in the preamble
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth', auto,node distance=2.75cm]
  \node[state] (start)      {};
  \node[state]         (s1) [right of=start, align=left]  {isProvider\\Enabled};
  \node[state]         (s2) [right of=s1] {};
  \node[state]         (s3) [right of=s2] {};
  \path[->] (start)  edge      node {} (s1)
        (s1) edge              node[text width=1cm,align=center, pos=.4] {requestLocation\\Updates} (s2)
        (s2) edge              node[text width=1cm,align=center, pos=.3 ]{addGps\\StatusListener} (s3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I want to decrease the distance from node start to node s1 to 1cm... but only that distance between nodes. All the other edges should stay 2.75 centimeters. Any ideas or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You might want to avoid `right of=` syntax and switch to `right= of s1` syntax with `positioning` library. Then individual tweaks are possible with `\node[state] (s1) [right = 0.5cm of start, align=left]  {isProvider\\Enabled};`

Comment: Please, always add to your questions *complete* minimal documents instead of just snippets.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the increased functionality of `right` (and similars) provided by the `positioning` library (see Section ***16.5.3 Advanced Placement Options*** of the `pgf` manual):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,automata}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth', auto,node distance=2.75cm]
  \node[state] (start)      {};
  \node[state]         (s1) [right=1cm of start, align=left]  {isProvider\\Enabled};
  \node[state]         (s2) [right of=s1] {};
  \node[state]         (s3) [right of=s2] {};
  \path[->] (start)  edge      node {} (s1)
        (s1) edge              node[text width=1cm,align=center, pos=.4] {requestLocation\\Updates} (s2)
        (s2) edge              node[text width=1cm,align=center, pos=.3 ]{addGps\\StatusListener} (s3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You need to correct the placement of the labels; as they are right now the text overlaps.

Comment: I compiled your code above and the result is not so nice. :-)

Comment: @azetina it is not *my* code; I used the OP's code, and yes it's ugly and that's why I didn't upload an image.

Comment: Ugly! I would rather say inappropriate :-)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina You are overriding the style of `state` which is predefined in the automata library (lack of mwe is in action here).

Comment: @percusse Ah; since the OP didn't provide a full MWE I assumed he had forgotten the definition of `state`, so I provided a quick one; I'll update the answer. Thank you.